# C getting TRUE (int form) address of a pointer without considering type

Tags: c, pointers

I know I can print an address using:

```
printf("%p\n",(void*)&a);
```

Is there a way to just access the address (=int representing place in memory) of a variable?

A possible workaround is atoi of sprintf %p but common, is there a cleaner way?

I need that for a Nachos project.
What I am trying to do is writing into the return register the address of an object I created in the kernel.

Comment: I do not really get what you want to express with these words: "*... is atoi of sprintf %p but common ...*"

Comment: Could you please elaborate what it is that you need?

Comment: "A possible workaround is atoi of sprintf %p but common" will not work when the printed text is hexadecimal or non-numeric like `"1234:5678"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cast a `void *` to a `uintptr_t`, which is an integer type large enough to represent a pointer.

```
uintptr_t p = (uintptr_t)(void *)&a;
```

Note that the double cast is needed, as the standard states the conversion is only valid between a `uintptr_t` and a `void *`.

Comment: Thanks. Thats exactely what I wanted, which was not simply passing pointers values around ;p

Answer (score 2):

A pointer can always be converted to an integer type. There's even a type that is guaranteed to be able to hold any (`void *`) pointer value, so converting it back to an actual pointer produces the original pointer: `uintptr_t`. There's also `intptr_t` as a signed type if you for some reason need the pointer value as signed.

**But:** I don't think you really need that. Reading your last sentence gives me the impression that you just have to pass pointer values around, so maybe you should explain your **actual** problem a bit better.

Comment: Detail: "... produces an _equivalent_ pointer" - potentially  not the same bit pattern pointer.

Comment: @chux well, the standard says "they compare equal", so it's the original one. I don't think stuff like padding bits etc are relevant in *this* context.

Comment: Even with no padding bits: the original and converted pointer bits patterns may differ. Pointers  `p12340010` and `p12350000` could point to the same place in memory.  As the spec details:  "they compare equal", not "have the same representation".  C supports many memory architectures.

Comment: @chux and I didn't even talk about representations, they're not relevant in this context. If you have different representations for the number `42`, some processing that results in `42` again still gives you *the original number*.